# Date format parsing string java

Tags: java, date

I got function:

```
    public boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZ");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
      dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

And I need to verify if string: '`2015-01-06T10:51:26.227+0100`' is date, but funtion always return false. Could anybody tell me if my dateDormat: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZ"` is correct?
I read a lot of questions about formatting date, but I think my dateFormat is still not correct.

Comment: Do you know such thing as DEBUG?

Comment: Have the formatter format the actual date, then look at the output and see if it matches what you are trying to parse. But I guess the `:sss` of the format is not correct. It should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: Ok, I wrote something like this to get test if its correct: `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        Date date = new Date();
        String str = dateFormat.format(date);` and on output I got: a: 2016-08-19T13:05:022+0200 so it's not generating miliseconds correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `:sss` part of the format is not correct. That would be 3 seconds, no Millis and a missing dot.

**It should be** :

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

To debug this: Have the formatter format the current date, then look at the output and see if it matches what you are trying to parse.

The above pattern is actually taken from [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - Examples Section.

**In Java 8** you should use the new Date/Time classes like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/982149) answer.

Comment: Thanks Bro, now it works fine :)

Answer (score 4):

Errors

- missing milliseconds `S`
- missing dot `.` between seconds and milliseconds
- putting 3 seconds `s`

Your format should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

No formatting pattern necessary.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-01-06T10:51:26.227+0100" ).toInstant() );
```

For invalid inputs, catch [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

## java.time

Other Answers are correct but use outdated classes. The troublesome old legacy date-time classes have been supplanted by java.time classes.

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time uses ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing and generating strings. So need to specify a parsing pattern.

Your input has an offset-from-UTC at the end. So [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-01-06T10:51:26.227+0100" );
```

Catching a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) will indicate the input data is invalid.

If you must have a [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object for use with old code not yet updated for java.time types, you can convert. Look for new methods added to the old classes for convenient conversions.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```